# TimeoutException when producing event from callback

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm experiencing producer timeouts when I try to send messages from within another send's `ListenableFutureCallback`, but it does not occur if I wait for the result synchronously and don't use the callback. After a few messages errors like can be seen:

```
...[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='...' to topic ...: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic ... not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here is the example code:

```
// This produces the TimeoutException
kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord)
  .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(failureMessage);
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(successMessage); // <- timeout here
      }
    });

// This does work as expected
kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get();
kafkaTemplate.send(successMessage);
```

I haven't found in the docs that producing a message from another producer's callback is forbidden, or is it related to some other configs?

Answer (score 0):

Test with the code below. Message can be successfully sent in `onSuccess` without timeout. Can you paste the whole sample code?

```
public class TestProducer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestProducer.class);

    // kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
    // kafka-topics --create --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic test_callback --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);

        KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("test_callback", 0, "key", "data");

        ProducerRecord<String, String> failureMessage = new ProducerRecord<>("test_callback", 0, "failed", "failed data");
        ProducerRecord<String, String> successMessage = new ProducerRecord<>("test_callback", 0, "success", "success data");

        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord)
                .addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                        kafkaTemplate.send(failureMessage);
                        // System.out.println("onFailure");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                        kafkaTemplate.send(successMessage); // <- timeout here
                        System.out.println("onSuccess");
                    }
                });


        // kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get();
        // kafkaTemplate.send(successMessage).get();

        ThreadUtils.sleepQuietly(1000000);
    }
}
```